# Vertical align img in row - twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problems with img vertical align in Twitter Bootstrap 3. So, here is HTML:

```
<div class="container center-block">
        <div class="row slider">
            <div class="col-md-1 left-arrow"><img src="img/left-arrow.png"/></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 brand"><img src="img/brand.png"/></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 brand"><img src="img/brand.png"/></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 brand"><img src="img/brand.png"/></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 brand"><img src="img/brand.png"/></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 brand"><img src="img/brand.png"/></div>
            <div class="col-md-1 right-arrow"><img src="img/right-arrow.png"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How I can center image vertically in `.left-arrow` and `.right-arrow` divs? Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bkzPE/. It's will be a slider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with this css

```
    .container .row { float:left; width:100%; }
    .container div { float:left; }
    .left-arrow { margin-right:10px; }
    .right-arrow { margin-left:10px; }
```